# Form being submitted doesn't send filled fields after an empty field

Tags: php, forms

So I have a form online that works perfectly if every field is filled, or if you fill out 90% of the form, but if you filled out 6/7 fields and leave the second one empty then the rest of the fields aren't emailed. I've been Googling for a couple of hours and don't think I've searched for the correct problem. Here's the code that actually does the emailing:

```
$response = array();
$error = false;
$message = '';
if(empty($_POST) && !isset($_POST['send']))
{
    $response['message'] = 'You have to submit the contact form first.';
    $error = true;
}else{
    unset($_POST['send']);
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$val)
    {
        if($val == '')
        {
            $error = false;
            $response['message'] = 'All fields are required';
            break;
        }
        $message .= '<p>' . htmlspecialchars($key) . ': ' . htmlspecialchars($val) . '</p>';
    }
}
if(!$error)
{
    $subject = 'New message from Aguettant contact form';
    $headers   = array();
    $headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
    $headers[] = "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
    $headers[] = "From: contact@biosyent.com";
    $headers[] = "Reply-To: {$_POST['Email']}";
    $headers[] = "Subject: {$subject}";
    $headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();
    if(mail('xxxx@aol.io',$subject,$message,implode("\r\n", $headers)) !== FALSE)
    {
        // redirect
        header("Location: thankyou.php");
        die();

    }else{
       $response['message'] = 'Something went wrong. Please try again.';
    }
```

I've discerned that it has to do with the else / foreach, but if I comment that out I get an email with no content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is an empty field, you break out of your loop and stop appending the fields.

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$val)
    {
        if($val == '')
        {
            $error = false;
            $response['message'] = 'All fields are required';
            break; // <-- here
        }
        $message .= '<p>' . htmlspecialchars($key) . ': ' . htmlspecialchars($val) . '</p>';
}
```

If you remove that break it should work as expected.

Comment: Ahhh snap, this worked! It's always that one line of code. Thanks for that, @jordan!